# Jquery - list each children in div by z-index from lower to highest

Tags: jquery, z-index, each, highest

I want to list all children in DIV by jQuery. But I need order this children by z-index. From lower to highest.

[**jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/uv2kqj1L/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="z-index: 1; ">1b</div>
    <div style="z-index: 10;">10</div>
    <div style="z-index: 3;">3a</div>
    <div style="z-index: 5;">5b</div>
    <div style="z-index: 7;">7</div>
    <div style="z-index: 2;">2</div>
    <div style="z-index: 3;">3b</div>
    <div style="z-index: 5;">5a</div>
    <div style="z-index: 1;">1a</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.container').children().each(function () {
    alert( $(this).css('z-index') );
});
```

I need to get ordered output like :

```
1b
1a
2
3a
3b
5b
5a
7
10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
function sort_li(a, b){
  return (parseInt(a.style.zIndex,10)) > (parseInt(b.style.zIndex,10)) 
}

$(".container div").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.container');
```

**### Working Demo**

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't understand how to use this. Please, can you make jsfiddle example ? Thank you. :)

Comment: Please , can you update with jsfiddle ? Thank you :)

Comment: @Patrik: hey patric. sorry i forgot to put the fiddle. sure will update in morning

Comment: Please, it is important for me :-)

Comment: @Patrik:hey. sorry for the late update. i was busy with some other work so couldnt come on SO. check the fiddle.

Comment: @GDY: Depends on the HTML you have. Please post a new question for same.

Comment: You cannot vanilla sort jquery objects. You have to convert the jquery result with get into a vanilla array and then fire the sort. Your "working demo" just doesn't work ;)